# Create mergeable priority queue interface structure

Tags: c#, data-structures, interface

I have following interfaces:

```
public interface IPriorityQueue<T>
{
    int Size { get; }
    void Insert(T val);
    T Max();
    void DeleteMax();
}

public interface IMergeablePriorityQueue<T> : IPriorityQueue<T>
{
   IPriorityQueue<T> Union(IPriorityQueue<T> Queue);
}
```

`Union` is the operation of merging two queues. 
 
Now in my implementation, which is leftist heap, I want to simplify complexity of `Union` and just operate on references to roots of heaps:

```
public class LeftistHeap<T> : IMergeablePriorityQueue<T>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private Node root = null;

    private LeftistHeap(Node newRoot, int newSize) {...}

    public LeftistHeap<T> Union(LeftistHeap<T> Q)
    {
        return new LeftistHeap<T>(Union(root, Q.root), Size + Q.Size);
    }
    private static Node Union(Node node1, Node node2) {...}
    ...
}
```

But this `Union` does not implement interface's `Union`.
 
I thought I could cast `IPriorityQueue` reference to `LeftistHeap` or make `Queue` parameter dynamic, but it's not a solution I'm looking for. Is there a neat way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution:

```
public interface IMergeablePriorityQueue<TQ, T> : IPriorityQueue<T>
    where TQ : IMergeablePriorityQueue<TQ, T>
{
    TQ Union(TQ Queue);
}
```

And then in every implementation of `IMergeable...` interface I just put current type into TQ parameter:

```
public class LeftistHeap<T> : IMergeablePriorityQueue<LeftistHeap<T>, T>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public LeftistHeap<T> Union(LeftistHeap<T> Q)
    {
        return new LeftistHeap<T>(Union(root, Q.root), Size + Q.Size);
    }
    ...
}
```

Similar problem is described here: [How to reference current class type using generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070766/how-to-reference-current-class-type-using-generics)

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to implement the method exactly as specified in the interface.

Also, you cannot rely on the parameter being a LeftistHeap, the caller can pass any object implemeting IPriorityQueue (of course, you can choose a more effective implementation if the parameters happens to be a LeftistHeap).